# Cron Job in magento is not working

Tags: magento

I am creating a module for cron jobs but it is not working.

My files:
**config.xml**

```
<config>
<global>
    <models>
        <mss_sunrise>
            <class>Mss_Sunrise_Model</class>
        </mss_sunrise>                         
    </models>
</global>
<crontab>
     <jobs>
        <mss_sunrise>
                    <!--<schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>-->
            <schedule><cron_expr>*/10 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                    <run><model>sunrise/observer::updateproductprice</model></run>
        </mss_sunrise>
       </jobs>
```

**Observer.php**

```
class Mss_Sunrise_Model_Observer

  {
public static function updateproductprice()
{

Mage::log("WORKS!",null,'cronjon.log');
}}
```

I have also added file in etc>modules.
Is there any thing that i forget to do, please let me know where i am doing wrong?

Comment: have you scheduled cron.php or cron.sh with your server cron

Comment: no, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

hi There is small mistake.

IN

```
 sunrise/observer::updateproductprice
```

**should be**

mss_sunrise/observer::updateproductprice

**As this format is**

```
modeltype/modelclass::functionname
```

as you model define in global tag your model type is
mss_sunrise